# Remove query string and leave parameter in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help with htaccess. Would you be so kind to assist a little bit?
I have a URL like this

```
https://example.com/index.php?p=application-intelligence
```

[or]

```
https://example.com/?p=application-intelligence
```

Basically the index.php is passed some parameter 'home' to know which page to load i.e. home.php
So I've tried to follow your post on your blog but with not much luck.

So I'd like the final code to be

https://example.com/application-intelligence

Here's my code.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

Also for the
https://example.com?p=home

I'd like it to be just

https://example.com

since it's the default page

Link: https://krugle.webtuits.com?application-intelligence

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: It looks like you already have .htaccess code in place.

Comment: So your index.php is apparently expecting the page name to be passed under the parameter name `p` - but you did not provide any parameter of that name in your rewritten URL. You actually want `index.php?p=$1` there.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]` Tried that didn't see any difference or I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've updated the OT with better clarfication

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work. What I'm I missing?

Comment: I've updated the OT with a link and a better description of what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite Query String to Path with htaccess
Let's say we have this URL:

http://example.com/users.php?name=tania
And we want this URL:

http://example.com/users/tania
we can do so with the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?users/(.*?)/?$ /users.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /users\.php\?name=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?users\.php$ /users/%1? [L,R=301]
```

we can even still GET the URL query

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '<br>';

print_r($_GET);
```

Comment: Thank you I've already tried that from Tania's website and doesn't work. I've been probably through every link that I could find ;)

Comment: could you share your link ?

Comment: I've updated the OT with a link and a better description

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've updated the OT with better clarfication